# How to list snapshots that DONT have a specific tag using Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm trying to find the snapshots that don't have a certain tag.

For snapshots, I want all snapshots that don't have the `Do-Not-Delete` tag. No matter what is the value of a tag.

This is what I'm doing now:

```
snaps_to_remove = ec2_client.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds=account_ids)
    for snap in snaps_to_remove['Snapshots']:
        # Remove all snapshots with the tag Do-Not-Delete functionality goes here
        print(snap)
```

I don't think if there's a filter for negative comparison based. What is the correct way to loop through and get filter out the list with the specific tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the snapshot contains Tags and one of the tags has a Key of 'Do-Not-Delete', skip the snapshot:

```py
snaps_to_remove = ec2_client.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds=account_ids)
for snap in snaps_to_remove['Snapshots']:
    # Skip snapshots with a Do-Not-Delete tag
    if 'Tags' in snap and [tag for tag in snap['Tags'] if tag['Key'] == 'Do-Not-Delete']:
        continue
    print(snap)
```